# Message sent to wrong endpoint intermittently

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

We send requests to our partner's "SubmitRequest" web service endpoint:
https://tempuri.org/soap?service=SubmitRequest
and retrieve responses from "RetrieveResponse" web service endpoint:
https://tempuri.org/soap?service=RetrieveResponse

We send 1000+ messages per **day**. We use C#.

Now our partner complains there is 1 or 2 messages being sent to the wrong endpoint per **week**, i.e.
 requests were sent to "RestrieveResponse" 
 or retrieved response from "SubmitRequest".

Sometimes the message was immediately resubmitted with the correct endpoint, but not always.

Could anyone here help please? Any suggestion/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem requests are originating from your ip?

Comment: Yes. Our partner sent us back the problem message with the receiving time, which matches the message and sending time logged on our server.